# OSB/Desktop audio on Ubuntu cannot be directed to Streamyard/Chrome microphone

Tags: obs

I have setup OBS on Ubuntu. I have virtual webcam working on OBS with Streamyard.
However, I am not able direct audio  from OBS into Streamyard/Chrome browser. I need a software/virtual microphone. Has anybody found a straight forward solution?

Thank you in Advance.